# LibreOffice OpenOffice Container Window caption text java, C++

Tags: java, sdk, openoffice.org, libreoffice, titlebar

I am working with LibreOffice SDK. I was testing with to open writer and inserting text in it. But I have not found a way about accessing the window title bar caption using SDK.

```
    public class DocumentLoader {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if ( args.length < 1 ) {
            System.out.println(
                "usage: java -jar DocumentLoader.jar \"<URL|path>\"" );
            System.out.println( "\ne.g.:" );
            System.out.println(
                "java -jar DocumentLoader.jar \"private:factory/swriter\"" );
            System.exit(1);
        }

        com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext xContext = null;

        try {
            // get the remote office component context
            xContext = com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
            System.out.println("Connected to a running office ...");

            // get the remote office service manager
            com.sun.star.lang.XMultiComponentFactory xMCF =
                xContext.getServiceManager();

            Object oDesktop = xMCF.createInstanceWithContext(
                "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext);

            com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader xCompLoader =
                UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                 com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader.class, oDesktop);

            String sUrl = args[0];
            if ( sUrl.indexOf("private:") != 0) {
                java.io.File sourceFile = new java.io.File(args[0]);
                StringBuffer sbTmp = new StringBuffer("file:///");
                sbTmp.append(sourceFile.getCanonicalPath().replace('\\', '/'));
                sUrl = sbTmp.toString();
            }

            // Load a Writer document, which will be automatically displayed
            com.sun.star.lang.XComponent xComp = xCompLoader.loadComponentFromURL(
                sUrl, "_blank", 0, new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue[0]);

com.sun.star.lang.XComponent xTextDocument = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                 com.sun.star.frame.XTextDocument.class, xComp);

            if ( xComp != null )
                System.exit(0);
            else
                System.exit(1);
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

As I have xTextDocument and I can get size and different attribute.
e.g.     `xTextDocument.getCurrentController().getFrame().getcontainerWindow().getPosSize();`

But what is the way to get the title bar text?

Comment: This was [cross-posted to the Apache OpenOffice community forum](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=78253). This was helpfully noted in an answer below, but since that was not an answer, I'll ask for that to be deleted (please always declare x-posting, thanks).

Answer (score 2):

After long experimenting, I have found the solution.

I have fixed it using XTitle. This interface could be used to type cast frame of window into XTitle. Then it works fine.